# How can i prevent adding duplicate entry?

Tags: c#, duplicates

What should i add in this code? I should avoid adding duplicate entries in my code. Thanks in advance

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Categories VALUES(@Category)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", txtName.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("/Admin/Categories/Add.aspx");
```

Comment: Add a unique constraint to the column and swallow the exception or add `if not exits` logic to your insert SQL.  Depends on the DB your using - add a tag to identify it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExecuteScalar() to return the value from 1st row and 1st column of any query. Do a select count and check if it returns 1.

```
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) from Categories where Category = @1", con))
{
    con.Open();
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", txtName.Text);
    int userCount = (int) sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    if(userCount == 1)
    {
        //already exists
    }
    else
    {
        //proceed
    }
}
```

Also while designing the database its better to make it a primary key.

As suggested by @Alex, use the below query instead of what you have,

```
cmd.CommandText = "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE CATEGORY=@1) INSERT INTO Categories VALUES(@1)";
```

Comment: Do note that someone could insert a value between your two queries. I would use an UNIQUE constraint to ensure data integrity.

Comment: Thanks. I thought making it primary key would take care of that.

Comment: count(*) is pretty toxic to check for a value, as is needing two trips to the db and ignoring atomicity.

Comment: Sure, if it's the primary key the DB will ensure the unicity.

Answer (score 0):

Solution one: add a constraint on the field (column) Category - or whatever your field is called in your database and catch an exception when it already exists in your database.

Solution two: check inside your query whether the value already exists.

Both solutions can throw an exception or one can use the return value of `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`, which is the number of rows affected, likewise:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  con.Open();
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
  cmd.Connection = con;
  cmd.CommandText = "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT Category FROM Categories WHERE Category=@Category) INSERT INTO Categories VALUES(@Category)";
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", txtName.Text);
  int affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();

  if (affectedRows == 1) //1 record was updated, thus we can conclude that the record was successfully inserted
  {
    Response.Redirect("/Admin/Categories/Add.aspx");
    //Perform other logic ...
  }
```

Remember when you place a constraint on the field `Category`, it will throw the Exception before `if (affectedRows == 1)`.